# Reload a .js file without pressing F5

Tags: javascript, jquery

i load a page with jquery `.load(file.php)`

i have a .js include in the file.php like: `<script src='js/script.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>`

When i load the file.php, he wouldn't load my JS file... does anybody know why and how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: It should get loaded and executed. What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: Use Chrome Developer Tools or Firefox Firebug (or equivalent tools in other browsers) to see what exactly is being requested from the server and why it may be failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the paths, make absolute path for .JS file, it should load.

```
<script src='/js/script.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
```

Just to be positive try it like this...

```
function ajax(url, selector){   
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
        success: function(data){
            $(selector).html(data);
        }
    });
}

ajax("file.php", "#mydiv");
```

Comment: the path is correct, and when i open the file.php directly it works.. but if i load the .php file with jquery he ignore the js file :\

Comment: Mark loaded content and **View Selection Source** (FF), check if HTML is not broken anywere. Probably is not but replace single quotes with double for **src=**...

Comment: its not broken.. but i think i cant load .js files with .load :\

Comment: I updated my answer, I use it this way and it works with no problem.

Comment: it still not working :[ ... he loads the file.php, but hes not refreshing the .js file i included in

Comment: Link your jQuery library source to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js and try again...

Comment: ok, i got news... i can load the js file for once... when i refresh my page the js file doesnt reload... so i have to unload it every time.. is there any solution?

Comment: I don't quite understand what unload means. Whatever you load it is in memory until you hit refresh, if you load it again via AJAX it get overwritten, or at least it should, depends what is in your JS file... Some code would be nice.

Comment: lol.. it works now... dont ask me why :D -- thank you for helping me :)

Comment: I know why, it is your fault :) no problemo.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why, but jQuery clear **script** elements when load html.

I`ve faced the same problem recently and after days searching in google I could implement a workaround for it.

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'mypage.aspx',
     data: eval('(' + MyData + ')'),
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function (data) {
         var $div = $('<div></div>').hide().appendTo($("#MY_DIV")).html(data).remove();
         var innerData = $(data).html();
         $("#MY_DIV").html(innerData);
     }
 });
```

Other possible way is add the scripts in the current page:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'mypage.aspx',
     data: eval('(' + MyData + ')'),
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function (data) {

         //Add to DOM scripts from the loaded page.
         var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
         var arr = data.match(/<script(.|\n|\t)*?script>/gi);
         if (arr != null) {
             for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                 if (arr[i].match(/<.*?src=.*?>/) != null) {
                     var sSrc = arr[i].match(/src=".*?"/)[0];
                     sSrc = sSrc.replace('src=', '').replace('"', '').replace('"', '');
                     var newScript = document.createElement('script');
                     newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
                     newScript.src = sSrc;
                     headID.appendChild(newScript);
                 }
             }
         }
         var arr = data.match(/<link(.|\n|\t)*?>/gi);
         if (arr != null) {
             for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

                 if (arr[i].match(/<.*?href=.*?>/) != null) {
                     var sHref = arr[i].match(/href=".*?"/)[0];
                     sHref = sHref.replace('href=', '').replace('"', '').replace('"', '');
                     var newLink = document.createElement('link');
                     newLink.rel = "stylesheet";
                     newLink.type = "text/css";
                     newLink.media = "all";
                     newLink.href = sHref;
                     headID.appendChild(newLink);
                 }
             }
         }

         $("#MY_DIV").html(data);
     }
 });
```

Comment: would be nice if you send me the entire code... cause it doesnt work for me .. maybe i made something wrong..

Comment: I usually put all my scripts in the one calling page. Maybe see [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1605-jQuery-AJAX-Strips-Script-Tags-And-Inserts-Them-After-Parent-Most-Elements.htm).

Answer (score 0):

How about just creating the script tag? Plus make sure the link is correct. Also, I heard that IE has some problems with dynamic script tags, so are you using IE?

```
$("<script src='js/script.js' type='text/javascript' ></script>").appendTo("head");
```